# Trouble sending temperature and humidity information from Pi to phone using IFTTT

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pi

Im trying to make a remote temperature and humidity monitoring system for a reptile tank as a proof of concept with my Pi model 3B+ and SenseHat. I have the SenseHat retrieving and displaying the info just fine, however I am running into issues when sending the information to my phone. I am using IFTTT and Pushbullet for this, but nothing I have tried is working. Here is my code thus far:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
import requests

sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()

number = [
0,1,1,1, # Zero
0,1,0,1,
0,1,0,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,0,1,0, # One
0,1,1,0,
0,0,1,0,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1, # Two
0,0,1,1,
0,1,1,0,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1, # Three
0,0,1,1,
0,0,1,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,0,1, # Four
0,1,1,1,
0,0,0,1,
0,0,0,1,
0,1,1,1, # Five
0,1,1,0,
0,0,1,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,0,0, # Six
0,1,1,1,
0,1,0,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1, # Seven
0,0,0,1,
0,0,1,0,
0,1,0,0,
0,1,1,1, # Eight
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,1,1,1, # Nine
0,1,0,1,
0,1,1,1,
0,0,0,1
]


#celcius_color = [255,0,0] # Red
fahrenheit_color = [0,255,0] # Green
#negative_celcius_color = [0,255,255] # Cyan
negative_fahrenheit_color = [0,0,255] # Blue
empty = [0,0,0] # Black
humidity_color = [0,255,255] # Cyan
negative_humidity_color = [255,0,0] # Red

display = [
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
]

while True:
    celcius = int(round(sense.get_temperature()))
    fahrenheit = int(round(1.8 * celcius + 32))
    humidity = int(round(sense.get_humidity()))

    if humidity < 0:
        humidity = abs(humidity)
        humidity_color = negative_humidity_color
    if fahrenheit < 0:
        fahrenheit = abs(fahrenheit)
        fahrenheit_color = negative_fahrenheit_color

    # Map digits to the display array
    pixel_offset = 0
    index = 0
    for index_loop in range(0, 4):
        for counter_loop in range(0, 4):
            display[index] = 
number[int(humidity/10)*16+pixel_offset]
                display[index+4] = 
number[int(humidity%10)*16+pixel_offset]
                display[index+32] = 
number[int(fahrenheit/10)*16+pixel_offset]
                display[index+36] = 
number[int(fahrenheit%10)*16+pixel_offset]
            pixel_offset = pixel_offset + 1
            index = index + 1
        index = index + 4

    # Color the temperatures
    for index in range(0, 64):
        if display[index]:
            if index < 32:
                display[index] = humidity_color
            else:
                display[index] = fahrenheit_color
        else:
            display[index] = empty

    
    
    # Display the temperatures
    sense.low_light = True # Optional
    sense.set_pixels(display)
    time.sleep(1)
c_val = 0
h_val = 0
celcius = int(round(sense.get_temperature()))
fahrenheit = int(round(1.8 * celcius + 32))
humidity = int(round(sense.get_humidity()))
while ((celcius['']>c_val) or (humidity['']>h_val)):
    celcius = int(round(sense.get_temperature()))
    fahrenheit = int(round(1.8 * celcius + 32))
    humidity = int(round(sense.get_humidity())) 
    
while True:
    celcius = int(round(sense.get_temperature()))
    fahrenheit = int(round(1.8 * celcius + 32))
    humidity = int(round(sense.get_humidity())) 
    if ((celcius['1']>c_val) or (humidity['1']>h_val)):
        print('monitoring...')
        r = requests.post('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/climate_monitor/with/key/MY_KEY', params={"value1":"str(fahrenheit)","value2":"str(humidity)","value3":"none"})
        time.sleep(5)
        celcius = int(round(sense.get_temperature()))
        fahrenheit = int(round(1.8 * celcius + 32))
        humidity = int(round(sense.get_humidity()))
```

of course, where I have "MY_KEY" in the IFTTT link, "MY_KEY" is just a placeholder for security purposes while posting this. I have the correct key in my file on the Pi.

Any help is greatly apprecitated

Comment: If all the code to obtain and display the temperature and humidity works fine, you can remove it and make a simple loop that sends an increasing number every 5 seconds to IFTTT...

Comment: "nothing I have tried is working" does not describe where in the code you are having trouble.

Comment: See also how you should try to present an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), while we understand a Pi might be needed for the reproducible part. The reptile tank surely can be mocked :)

Comment: Where I am running into the issue is with the IFTTT portion of the code. The code reads and displays temperature and humidity perfectly fine, but does not transmit that information to IFTTT. I think I am having issues with the  last 'While' and 'While true' lines of the code. I believe there is an issue with my variables and parameters but I do not know how to assign the temperature and humidity variables to IFTTT

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending a temperature and humidity, you are sending a piece of code because you have enclosed your string (which is already a string) in double quotes.

Run like this instead:

```
import requests

fahrenheit = 73
humidity   = 95

r = requests.post('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/climate_monitor/with/key/MY_KEY', params={"value1":str(fahrenheit),"value2":str(humidity),"value3":"none"})
```